# Cannot replace more than one character at a time with a ReplaceText processor in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to insert a comma between braces in a FlowFile.

I receive json objects and merge them together with a process. After the merge I get this:

```
{"tag":"a","bag":"b"}{"tag":"c","bag":"d"}
```

I want it to end up like this after the ReplaceText processor:

```
{"tag":"a","bag":"b"},{"tag":"c","bag":"d"}
```

However my ReplaceText process doesn't work. I have it set up like this:

[image]

With this process, nothing gets replaced.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just verified this behavior works successfully with the configurations and input/expected output you provided on NiFi 1.12.0-SNAPSHOT. If you examine the data provenance of the `ReplaceText` processor, is the flowfile content identical before & after? You should see that the content claim offset is different and that the content size changed from 42 bytes to 43. Are you seeing bulletins or failures? Is there any useful information in the `nifi-app.log` file?

Comment: make sure you dont have yje }{ on diff lines

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add demarcator in MergeContent if you use it in you process
But you variant still must work. I try this on 1.10 and content has been changed.